# Sticky Menu - prevent loading on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a sticky menu part way down on my page, so that when a user scrolls to it, it sticks to the top. When the user scrolls back up, it will stop sticking to the top when you reach where the sticky menu is located on the page.

That all works fine. The only problem is that if someone refreshes the page while the sticky menu is at the top, it won't un-stick when you pass it on the page (it stays stuck no matter where you are).

Is there something I can do to remove that?

```js
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu-t')
        var menuPosition = menu.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
            if (window.pageYOffset >= menuPosition) {
                menu.style.position = 'fixed';
                menu.style.top = '0px';
            } else {
                menu.style.position = 'static';
                menu.style.top = '';
            }
        });
```

```css
.page-section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-section.page-section-center {
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}


.menu-t {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-bottom: 1px #eee dotted;
}
.menu-t li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.menu-t a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #32404E !important;
  -webkit-transition: color ease 0.3s;
  -o-transition: color ease 0.3s;
  transition: color ease 0.3s;
}
.menu-t a:hover {
  color: #2db2e9 !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="page-section">
  <br/>
  <br/>
    <br/>
  <br/>
  </section>
<section class="page-section page-section-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <ul class="menu-t">
      <li>ITEM</li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="text-thick">What Is</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#" class="text-thick">How</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="text-thick">You're In Good Company</a>
        </li>
      <li>ITEM</li>
    </ul>
</section>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `DOMContentLoaded` eventListener to your javascript.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var menu = document.querySelector('.menu-t')
  var menuPosition = menu.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
      if (window.pageYOffset >= menuPosition) {
          menu.style.position = 'fixed';
          menu.style.top = '0px';
      }
      else {
          menu.style.position = 'static';
           menu.style.top = '';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have resolved the issue. Still sticks throughout the whole page.